# Select description of ID MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a problem when trying to change the "idjogo" on "select * from equipas " from a number to its actual "nomejogo"

I have tried this command but it outputs more than 1 row.

```
select nomeequipa, (select nomejogo from videojogo left join equipas on videojogo.idjogo = equipas.idjogo) from equipas;
```

This is my code:

```
drop table if exists videoequipa;
drop table if exists equipas;
drop table if exists videojogo;


create table videojogo(
    idjogo         INTEGER(2) AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    nomejogo       NVARCHAR(25),
    genero         enum('fps','rpg','moba','sports')
);

create table equipas(
    idequipa       INTEGER(2) AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    nomeequipa     NVARCHAR(25),
    idjogo        INTEGER(2),
    Constraint Fk001 foreign key (idjogo) references videojogo(idjogo)
);

create table videoequipa(
    idequipa       INTEGER(2),
    idjogo         INTEGER(2),
    primary key (idequipa,idjogo)

);


Insert into videojogo (nomejogo,genero) values ('Counter Strike','fps');
Insert into videojogo (nomejogo,genero) values ('League of Legends','moba');
Insert into videojogo (nomejogo,genero) values ('Dota 2','moba');
Insert into videojogo (nomejogo,genero) values ('Rocket League','sports');
Insert into videojogo (nomejogo,genero) values ('Overwatch','fps');



Insert into equipas (nomeequipa,idjogo) values ('Dignitas',1);
Insert into equipas (nomeequipa,idjogo) values ('Fnatic',1);
Insert into equipas (nomeequipa,idjogo) values ('Fnatic',2);
Insert into equipas (nomeequipa,idjogo) values ('Flypside',4);
Insert into equipas (nomeequipa,idjogo) values ('Titan',3);
Insert into equipas (nomeequipa,idjogo) values ('Ninjas in Pijamas',1);
Insert into equipas (nomeequipa,idjogo) values ('Titan',5);
Insert into equipas (nomeequipa,idjogo) values ('Titan',3);
Insert into equipas (nomeequipa,idjogo) values ('Dignitas',2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `left join` in nested select. Below should work:

```
SELECT e.nomeequipa, v.genero
FROM equipas e LEFT JOIN videojogo v ON e.idjogo = v.idjogo;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9719b/2/0)**.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I wanted!